# Asp.net MVC : Pass a value from webgrid text box column to the controller

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, webgrid

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    function save(id, notes)
    {
        alert('want to save row id ? ' + id + notes)
    }

</script>
```

```html
 @webGrid.GetHtml(mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
                     tableStyle: "table table-sm table-hover table-striped table-bordered table-row,
                     headerStyle: "", rowStyle: "",
                     (columns: webGrid.Columns(webGrid.Column("Notes", format: @<text>
        <input type="text" name="txtNotes" id="txtNotes" style="width:100%;" />
         <input type="hidden" name="RecID" value="@item.RecID" />
        <a href="#" onclick="save('@item.RecID', '#txtNotes.val()');return false;">Save</a>
        </text>, canSort: false))
```

Hi All, In the above code I am trying to read the value from the txtNotes, after user enters something into an empty textbox or tries to edit an already existing notes. I am not able to get the value of txtNotes in either of the cases. Can someone please point me where am I going wrong?

Thank you very much!!

Comment: You can use one of the techniques shown here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563638/how-do-i-get-the-value-of-text-input-field-using-javascript. You can't get the value with Razor code since that executes before the user even sees the page.

Comment: Hi I tried with document.getElementByID("txtNotes").Value , this works only for first row and all others have the value entered from the first box. I am not sure how to correct it. I want something specific to webgrid.

Comment: function save(id)
    {
    
       var notes =  document.getElementById("_txtNotes").value;
        alert('want to save row id ? ' + id + notes)
    }

Comment: element id need to be unique

Comment: @Jasen how can it be unique for each row?

Comment: If your id are not unique then you don't have valid html. You'll need to create a unique key for each record ("txtNotes" + RecId) so your javascript can reference a record arbitrarily. If you can't or don't want to do that you'll need to structure your html so you can reference the child or parent nodes when you enter the onclick handler -- at which point you can find among the children the input by name.

Comment: Thank you @Jasen. I got it. Thank you so much...